# CodeIgniter 3 get all form post data and insert into database without making an array like cake php 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hey guys can anyone suggest me how to insert all post data into database in codeigniter 3 like cake php 3 without making an array.
In cakephp 3 I use to write code like this

```
$this->loadModel("Users");
$users = $this->Users->newEntity();
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $users = $this->Users->patchEntity($users, $this->request->data);
      `$this->Posts->save($users)`
}
```

so if you will see above code I have not made any array to insert into database
So I want to know that does codeigniter provide such type of facility?????

Comment: You could literally READ the *entire* CodeIgniter manual in only a couple hours and find out for yourself:  https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in your model Users like

```
function saveUser($data){
         if(!empty($data)){
                $this->db->insert('user', $data);
          }
}
```

and in your controller function you can use code like:

```
$this->loadModel("Users");
$post_data = $this->input->post();
$this->Users->saveUser($post_data);
```

Hope it will help you... let me know if need any clarification or modification...